# SharePoint Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint

When I have a lookup column in a **Document Information Panel** (DIP), and I select an item, it is displaying the List Item ID instead of the text of the selected.

Are there anyway I can get the name and not the ID of the item that is looked up to?

It is obvious that I have selected the correct column when setting up the lookup field, but it defaults to the ID in a Word document's DIP panel.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to select the right column for lookup in the "Additional Column Settings" for a Lookup field type.

Comment: +1 This is when you edit/add a site column, so in the sharepoint UI.

Comment: No this is incorrect. We are talking about the Document Information Panel in word, everywhere else, it renders as the right column, but in Word, it grabs the ID when selecting from the drop down.

Comment: It does work in the DIP. Curious, do you guys use custom xsn for DIP.